# Procedural update of enum for a list in dynamic reconfigure

Tags: roscpp, dynamic-reconfigure

How to add/update to the drop down list created using ParameterGenerator's enum() method. In the .cfg file we can use a default list for populating the rqt_reconfigure drop down. I am looking forward to update the content procedurally runtime.

I am using ROS1 with a cpp node hence cannot use python